# downloading a software that States it requires windows?

Tags: software-installation

I want to buy this OS but I need it for work, I need to be able to download a software from a DVD from a company called whellen. The DVD says it requires windows xp with sp2, windows vista or windows 7. Will I be able to download it using Ubuntu?

Comment: download should not be a problem. even you can install it on Ubuntu using `wine`.

Comment: Buy?! Our OS is free of charge. "Whellen" Never heard of it. Google does not know it. Probably you can live without it too :+

Comment: Oh I did not know it was for free I saw it for sale on eBay, and it was a typo its called whelen and I can't live without it actually, like I said its for work. But thank you anyways.

Comment: Do I need to already have a OS in order to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [4+ Ways to Run Windows Software on Linux](http://goo.gl/dbdUC)

To me the best solution is to install Virtualbox (documentation there [VirtualBox/Installation](https://goo.gl/wnYmt6)

And then to install your version of Windows 7 via [Install windows 7 through virtual box](http://goo.gl/OxUqP4)

The only thing to be sure is that your processor supports virtualization.

The list on intel ones is here [About Intel® Virtualization Technology](http://goo.gl/MzBO2)

Then install your "whellen software" within the virtualbox directly from your PC DVD drive.